# Allow only certain characters

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to block all characters from being inputed except 0-9,a-z,A-Z  range only alphanumeric characters. So when someone types ! for examplee nothing is written into input. How can I do that?

Comment: Please be a bit more detailed. What context are you talking about? A form? Multiple forms?

Comment: @Pekka I mean in I have a form and inside I have a certain input field, and I want to allow only alphanumeric characters inside, if someone types something other such as .(dot) or any other character the character should not be written in the input. There is jQuery alphanumeric pack but its an overhead to include the whole new javascript for this simple functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a function that listens for the `onkeypress` event for the form field, then check to see if the form contains any unwanted characters, and if it does, you update the field with those characters removed.

Comment: You can also return `false` from your `onkeypress="function()"` to prevent the character being written

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you can use [Alphanumeric Plugin for jQuery](https://github.com/KevinSheedy/jquery.alphanum) :

```
$('#yourInput').alphanum();
```