# TextBox Not Allow Certain Characters & Symbols

Tags: php, html, forms, character

I have the form below in a PHP/HTML file:

```
<form method="post">
Username<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="16" name="username"><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up!" />
</form>
```

How would I make it so that it doesn't allow symbols like `&/.,'"\|;:}]{[+=` and it doesn't allow spaces and certain words?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use a server-side language.

Comment: @yoda: [Not true at all](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation). Why do you think that? In fact, a server-side language is not able to help here if you want to _prevent_ people from inputting invalid characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow only certain characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790406/allow-only-certain-characters)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: you can bypass javascript validations with Firebug or any software / plugin / hack that allows you to do such. The most secure way to control user input's is using a server-side language. You can, of course, use both options to ease the server job, but it's always a good option to do that kind of validation on the server.

Comment: @yoda: It's a good idea to do validation on the server, yes, but the OP is asking about physically restricting keypresses in an input control.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: couldn't see where he's asking for a client-side solution.

Comment: @yoda: The textbox exists on the clientside. The title of the question is about not allowing certain characters in the textbox. How on earth do you do that on the serverside?!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I don't think you're worried with the OP at all. Anyway, I gave my 2 cents, and most answers point to that as being preferable to any client-side solution alone. If the OP expects a client-side solution for his problem, he should clarify that, otherwise people will read the problem from a wider perspective an give their specs based on that, as I did.

Comment: @yoda: How do you know what I am and am not "worried" with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP use [preg_match();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) : `/^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/` would only allow:

```
a-z
0-9
_
-
```

between 3-16 characters.

With Javascript you can make the same for online editing (while typing).

[Some other RegExp @NetTutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear that you want validation on client side or server side.

On client side, you need javascript to do the validation for you, try to google jquery validation.

On server side, you need to write code to validate submitted data, one option is PHP builtin sanitizing and filtering - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters/

I think you should do both side validation. This is a good article to get started - http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/form-validation-using-php.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to prevent those keystrokes on the client side. However, you must escape characters and remove any special characters on the server to prevent being exploited.