# How can I limit an input field to allow only * and 0-9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I spent the whole day writing a very complex javascript. The missing ingredient is a JavaScript regular expression that only allows an input field to have * and numbers.

Do you think you can help?

Comment: What have you tried? There are many sites available on the web that will teach you how to write JavaScript regular expressions.  If you don't understand the code that goes into your work, you'll just end up with further problems down the line.

Comment: Yep, some of your attempts would be useful :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow only certain characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790406/allow-only-certain-characters)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
/^(\d|\*)*$/
```

See if that works

Answer (score 0):

the "`*`" character? You should be able to do something like `[\*0-9]+`.

You may need to escape twice (`\\*`)

**Update** as per the spec:

```
(\**|\d*)
```

either one or the other.

Comment: Inside `[]` you don't need to escape `*` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var bla = '123*', foo = '234*abc';
bla.match(/[*0-9]/g).length === bla.length; //=> true
foo.match(/[*0-9]/g).length === foo.length; //=> false
```

for input that has to be either '*' or numeric use
`/^\*$/.test([inputstr]) || /^\d+$/.test([inputstr])`

```
var foo = '**', bar = '123', bla = '*', foobar = 'abcd1*';
alert( /^\*$/.test(foo) || /^\d+$/.test(foo) );       //=> false
alert( /^\*$/.test(bar) || /^\d+$/.test(bar) );       //=> true
alert( /^\*$/.test(bla) || /^\d+$/.test(bla) );       //=> true
alert( /^\*$/.test(foobar) || /^\d+$/.test(foobar) ); //=> false
```

if 'numeric only' should include floats:
`/^\*$/.test(num) || !isNaN(Number(num))`

Comment: agh.. I need the input field to either support * or digits. Not both of them together..

Comment: BTW change "only * and 0-9"  in your question to "only * OR 0-9"